# Django can't open database in table

Tags: python, django, sqlite, templates, datatable

Django. I try printing userdata in a datatable. The query is successful but I cant see any data. I know that the database in o.k. I use sqlite. Only **"The query was successful"** is printed.

**Code:**

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

  args = {}
  args.update(csrf(request))

  args['form'] = UserProfileForm()
  args['my_data_dictionary'] = request.session['my_data_dictionary'] 


  try:
      profile = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
      args['profile'] = profile
      args['query_result'] = "The query was successful"

  except :
      args['query_result'] = "The query failed"

  return render_to_response('user_profile.html',args,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**user_profile.html**

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}

  {% block content %}

  {{ query_result }}

 <table>

    {% for item in profile.all %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ item }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

 </table>

   {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these two lines

```
profile = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
```

and

```
{% for item in profile.all %}
```

The first one will just return to you a single `User` object. This object won't have an `all` attribute, so the second `{% for %}` won't be executed! Instead of the `{% for %}` try `{{ profile }}`.

*Update*

First of all, I really don't know what this line

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

does. Please remove it from there ! Now, I suppose that the `User` is a normal `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. If yes, then you can do the following in your template:

```
The user {{ profile.username }} has the following name: {{ profile.first_name }} {{  profile.last_name }}
```

etc etc - check the docs to see all the fields of `User`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/

Comment: Ok. But I only get the username of the user . How can i get all the data/attributes/information about the user ?

Comment: I didn't know it was so simple. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

to fetch all the `User` objects
use:

```
profile = User.objects.all()
args['profile']= profile
```

and in html

```
{% if profile %}
    {% for usr in profile %}
       {{ usr }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are mistaking the code

```
{% for item in profile.all %}
{% endfor %}
```

To provide access to the fields of your model in your template.

Instead, to access user fields (data, attributes, etc.), you need to use the following in your template:

```
<tr> 
    <td>{{ profile.<user attribute> }}</td>
    <td>{{ profile.username }}</td>
</tr>
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/